# Import data from file to db with field association?

Tags: jquery, file-io

I'm having some issues about this thing:

I'm working on this script in php for import datas from csv file into mysql.

Because every file have different header I'm working on this "interface" where I would to make an association between fields from database and fields from file.

Actually I'm blocked on the most important part: How to finalize the association?
Actually I got this output:

```
<table>
    <tr>DATABASE</tr>
        <td id="db_1">COL_NAME_A</td>
        <td id="db_2">COL_NAME_B</td>
        <td id="db_3">COL_NAME_C</td>        
    </tr>

    <tr>FILE</tr>
        <td id="file_1">
            <select name="fileFieldsContainer">
                <option value="FILE_FIELD_A">FILE_FIELD_A</option>
                <option value="FILE_FIELD_B">FILE_FIELD_B</option>
                <option value="FILE_FIELD_C">FILE_FIELD_C</option>
        </td>
        <td id="file_2">
            <select name="fileFieldsContainer">
                <option value="FILE_FIELD_A">FILE_FIELD_A</option>
                <option value="FILE_FIELD_B">FILE_FIELD_B</option>
                <option value="FILE_FIELD_C">FILE_FIELD_C</option>
        </td>
        <td id="file_3">
            <select name="fileFieldsContainer">
                <option value="FILE_FIELD_A">FILE_FIELD_A</option>
                <option value="FILE_FIELD_B">FILE_FIELD_B</option>
                <option value="FILE_FIELD_C">FILE_FIELD_C</option>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now, via jquery how can i make a json where I make an association like:

```
DB_1 => FILE_1:SELECTED_VALUE

DB_2 => FILE_2:SELECTED_VALUE

DB_3 => FILE_3:SELECTED_VALUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is broken in many ways, firstly tr-element can't contain any text, secondly select-elements are not closed. Correct those. Then if I understood you correcly, you could utilize data-attributes to generate the object you need. Like so:

Html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="db_1">COL_NAME_A</td>
        <td id="db_2">COL_NAME_B</td>
        <td id="db_3">COL_NAME_C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="file_1" data-db="db_1" data-file="file_1" class="doStuff">
            <select name="fileFieldsContainer">
                <option value="FILE_FIELD_A">FILE_FIELD_A</option>
                <option value="FILE_FIELD_B">FILE_FIELD_B</option>
                <option value="FILE_FIELD_C">FILE_FIELD_C</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td id="file_2" data-db="db_2" data-file="file_2" class="doStuff">
            <select name="fileFieldsContainer">
                <option value="FILE_FIELD_A">FILE_FIELD_A</option>
                <option value="FILE_FIELD_B">FILE_FIELD_B</option>
                <option value="FILE_FIELD_C">FILE_FIELD_C</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td id="file_3" data-db="db_3" data-file="file_3" class="doStuff">
            <select name="fileFieldsContainer">
                <option value="FILE_FIELD_A">FILE_FIELD_A</option>
                <option value="FILE_FIELD_B">FILE_FIELD_B</option>
                <option value="FILE_FIELD_C">FILE_FIELD_C</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Js:

```
$(function () {
    var t = [];
    $(".doStuff").each(function () {
        var o = {};
        var innerO = {};
        innerO[$(this).data("file")] = $(this).find("select").val();
        o[$(this).data("db")] = innerO;
        t.push(o);
    });

    console.log(t);
});
```